# Select most repeated values and sort them in MySQL

Tags: mysql

let say I have this table

```
no | date       | no1   | no2    | no3   |
------------------------------------------
01 | 1993-05-01 | 0019  | 1124   | 0592  | 
02 | 1993-05-02 | 1234  | 4221   | 5543  | 
03 | 1993-05-03 | 4321  | 0019   | 0019  | 
04 | 1993-05-04 | 0019  | 1112   | 6876  |
```

What MySQL Query will return the most repeated number and sort them by latest date?

Comment: most repeated number in which column(s)?

Comment: hi Shredder, I need the most repeated number on all column. Tq

Comment: Tomalak Geret'kal, from the table we know 0019 is most repeated number. how to count on multiple column?

Comment: Still now clear.  Are you looking the highest repeats for a particular date across no1/no2/no3?  And if so, what do you desire if there are more than one numbers that share the highest counts?

For instance,

    1993-05-01   (all three occur once)
    1993-05-02   (all three occur once)
    1993-05-03   0019 occurs twice
    1993-05-04   (all three occur once)

?

Comment: @bug11 I just want to count how many 0019 appear and then sort them by latest date. Is union all help?

Comment: normalize your table, it's not even in the first normal form. If you normalize it, it will be quite easy to count the repeating groups.

Comment: I also think about to normalize that table but first try to find the solution if possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to "flatten" you data set first. You can do this by running 1 query for each column, then doing a UNION and a SELECT on the unions with a group by.

```
SELECT date, no, SUM(c) c FROM (
SELECT max(date) date, no1 AS no, count(no1) c FROM table GROUP BY no
UNION
SELECT max(date) date, no2 AS no, count(no1) c FROM table GROUP BY no
UNION
SELECT max(date) date, no3 AS no, count(no1) c FROM table GROUP BY no
) grouped_data GROUP BY no ORDER BY c DESC
```

Comment: thanks. It working perfectly, only sorting by date not giving the latest date. Thanks